# Solr with real time changing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr

We're  working on large eCommerce site which is based on ASP.NET MVC3(C#). We are planning to implement Solr for better search result.

There is a one feature named "Most Popular Product" in site.As named suggest,It displays most popular product on site based on how many times that particular product viewed by customer.

On Product detail page or product listing page,we distinguish it by putting an unique(most popular icon) icon which indicates most popular product.

Now our problem is that,How can we update flag or status that product identify as most popular  in solr index? or How can we relates this features with solr?

Note: It is very costly to update whole solr index for fulfill this functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't base the most popular product on views because that can be gamed. I would base it on actual purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html) to store popularity data for products (it's available in 3.6 too). This lets you update that field without the need to reindex anything.

Comment: Any document on how to use External File Field in Solr 3.6?

Comment: And any idea on its performance? Will it make Solr Slow? Or it is also cached and faster just like the solr?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few suggestions.  There may be more.

1. Have the most popular products (the one you know and the ones you guess to be popular) - in a separate Solr shard.  This core should be much smaller than the others.  Index updates and commits will be faster in this.
2. There is a solr feature in 4.0 [Near Real Time Search.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch) .  You can use this feature on this core described above (or even the whole index).  This feature requires solr 4.0
3. If you cannot use Solr 4.0 yet, then have a 'live' core and 'on-deck' core.  Update the on-deck core with new flags/statuses.  After this new data is committed, swap the on-deck with live core.  New searches on the now 'live' core has new data.  Repeat.
4. Turn off or reduce search warming queries in case of frequently changing index cores.